# DTFT of inverse of any function

Tags: linear-systems, dtft

[image]
In my book solution is given like this.
But i am solving like this , am i doing wrong??
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're doing it wrong. :) Inverse systems in time domain satisfy

$$h[n] * h_i[n] = \delta[n]$$

where $*$ denotes convolution and $h_i[n]$ is the impulse response of the inverse system. If you DTFT this equation, you'll get a).